# Using preg_replace need to replace random directory in an image src

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I have been struggling with this now for 2 hours and it's driving me nuts. And I don't think it is likely hard. I am using Wordpress and need to replace the IMG urls from an old path to a new path. Problem is..everything about the url is static except a particular directory which is random.

Example:

`https://cdn2.content.mysite.com/uploads/user/76eb326b-62ff-4d37-bf4b-01a428e2f9f6/0ffd6c15-8a13-437c-9661-36edfe11cb41/Image/b1493cd89a29c0a2d1d8e0939f05d8ee/booth_w640.jpeg`

should become

**/wp-content/uploads/imports/booth_w640.jpeg**

The bold part is random. So I have this in my wordpress functions.php

```php
function replace_content($content) {
    $reg = '#/https://cdn2.content.mysite.com/uploads/user/76eb326b-62ff-4d37-bf4b-01a428e2f9f6/0ffd6c15-8a13-437c-9661-36edfe11cb41/Image/([^/]+)#i';
    $rep = '/wp-content/uploads/imports';
    $content = preg_replace($reg, $rep ,$content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

but that isn't working. I can't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: `[.*]` would only match `.` and `*` literally.

Comment: So I am close then? Cause right now, Wordpress replaces ALL the content with nothing...versus replacing "just" the image src's in the content.

Comment: Just change `'#/https:` to `'#https:`

Comment: This is where my code resides at the moment..with the image src still not being properly replaced http://pastie.org/8444633

Comment: Use a `var_dump($content)` inside the function to check if it actually is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

```
function replace_content($content) {
    $reg = '#/static-part-of-url/([^/]+)#i';
    $rep = '/wp-content/uploads/imports';
    $content = preg_replace($reg, $rep ,$content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Using a different delimiter than `/` is better when trying to match URLs.

[Here](http://codepad.org/Gss5ooml) is the script in action.

Comment: Well, now the content shows up again..but the URL for the images is still the same.
<pre>
    function replace_content($content) {
        $reg = '#/https://cdn2.content.mysite.com/uploads/user/76eb326b-62ff-4d37-bf4b-01a428e2f9f6/0ffd6c15-8a13-437c-9661-36edfe11cb41/Image/([^/]+)#i';
        $rep = '/wp-content/uploads/imports';
        $content = preg_replace($reg, $rep ,$content);
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
</pre>

Comment: @BryanKohlmeier Can you put the end result of URL in your question as well? What the URL should be after replace filter I mean.

Comment: I don't post on stackoverflow obviously..sorry my edits are screwing up.

Comment: @BryanKohlmeier And what should it become after the regex-replace?

Comment: Sorry. if the BAD url is http://cdn2.content.mysite.com/uploads/user/76eb326b-62ff-4d37-bf4b-01a428e2f9f6/0ffd6c15-8a13-437c-9661-36edfe11cb41/Image/ddcd4ff2ca089e85efad45228464e1f9/file.jpg

I want it to become

/wp-content/uploads/imports/file.jpg

Comment: please note the ending slash on the directory named "Images/" not sure if that is screwing things up with the regex

Comment: When I try your code above (in the codepad), all the post content is there..but the image still points to the bad URL. So am I not using pre_replace in the correct way in order for the url to get replaced?

Answer (score 0):

I determined the answer to my problem using the below code

```
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $content, $match ) ;
$getURL = $match[1];
$urlArr = explode("/",$getURL);
$fileName = end($urlArr);
$newURL = "/blog/wp-content/uploads/imports/" . $fileName;
$content = str_replace($getURL, $newURL, $content);
```